# Can I solder a capacitor on a lifted trace

Tags: pad

I lifted and tore away a pad when soldering a capacitor on a PCB. The pad on the negative side is fine. Can I solder the capacitor lead onto the negative pad, and the other lead on the exposed trace for the positive pad?

Here is a picture so you can have a better idea:

[image]

I’m talking about the C7 capacitor pads.

Comment: Yes, you can - if you're careful.

Comment: You could also locate a via or a connection point elsewhere on the circuit and try to make a junction there. This method is also useful if you forget a trace in your design. Use a conductor with the appropriate gage based on the expected current. 

See for details: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/99

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to do is remove the protective mask that is over the negative track, leaving enough copper on air for soldering the negative lead.

Next, before soldering, I would degrease the copper and use some flux. Apply locally  litte bit of acetone, dry, isopropopanol, dry and flux in that order.

Finally proceed to solder the capacitor lead.